# Python: requests returning 403

Tags: python, request, python-requests, kraken.com

I used the requests package to communicate to an api (from api.kraken.com). Everything worked fine until suddenly the api keeps responding with an 403 error. I still can browse the [api](https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Assets).

My code (that used to work):

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Chrome/64.0.3282.119'})
s.get('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Assets')
```

Comment: Works here, both with your code and with `curl`.

Comment: 403 is “forbidden”. You may have come up against a rate limit or been behaving badly. Contact the providers of the api.